# What's the JsonDeserializer in Google java api client

Tags: google-app-engine, jackson, google-api-java-client

With Jackson library I can use custom Json deserializer, but I do not find this in Google Java Api Client (using Jackson). How can I do that?
Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: If you have apache.commons.lang then you can use, org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils Class for your need. It has both serializer and de-serializer.

Comment: I think it's not what I want. I need a Jackson Deserializer annotation for my POJO field. When I use JacksonFactory to parse a String to my object, my custom deserializer can be used.